# Nonsensical negative coefficent with multiple regression, without multicollinearity

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, multicollinearity

I am a bit confused with a result that came up with a multiple regression. I have these data

| X1 | X2 | Y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 287 | 4769 | 9972 |
| 291 | 5674 | 9732 |
| 308 | 3994 | 7999 |
| 315 | 3554 | 7138 |
| 321 | 5044 | 7642 |
| 330 | 5336 | 7765 |
| 334 | 5308 | 7827 |
| 317 | 3982 | 6945 |

I have run a multiple linear regression with X1 and X2 as independent variables. I get a coefficient of -53.2 for X1.
This is despite:
(i) X1 and Y having a positive correlation (R2 0.28)
(ii) me knowing for a fact that it does not make sense that if X1 increases Y should fall (Y is largely used to make X1). That's not ok
(iii) X1 and X2 being uncorrelated (VIF 1.0005)

Do you have any indication that can help explain this? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your data conflict with what you know, that's all.  Moreover, X1 and Y *clearly* are negatively, not positively, correlated: $R^2$ tells you nothing about the sign of correlation.

Comment: Ouch, you are right!